# Can I insert and lock a vector illustration in a word document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I work for a marketing department that gets constant copy edit requests for sales proposals that have been designed in illustrator and indesign. Is there a way for me to recreate the document in word by inserting and locking the illustrations, but still allowing anyone to edit the copy around it?

Answer (score 4):

I've been asked this question before, almost exclusively from people **who do not want to pay me anymore for my services and think there is an easy way out**.

They think to themselves: I'm going to get this designer to create promotional material, but I don't want to have to pay him to make the updates every time I change the date. Isn't there an easier way?

The answer is **NO**!

**You cannot properly duplicate professionally designed documents in Microsoft Word**, and I'll give you the same reasons that I gave my last client:

- Word cannot save with true bleed (edge to edge graphics are possible, but not past the edge, which is necessary for commercial printing)
- Word constantly messes with image resolution (most graphics end up lo-res)
- Word has a very hard time saving professional, print-ready files (try defining the ink profile for your next Word PDF save)

In summary, there is a reason that you had those documents designed in a professional program. There is a reason you pay for a professional to handle the files as well. Trying to do what you're suggesting will only make your company look **unprofessional**.

Comment: I want to +10 this. Word is for letters. The Adobe suite is for design.

Comment: I agree 100%... but there are requirements for docs to be rendered in Word (I just saw a government RFP with such a requirement).

Comment: I definitely see your point @Voxwoman, but the nature of OP's request makes it clear that they are specifically concerned with the illustrations (and that the previous briefs were acceptable in an Adobe-rendered PDF format). If the document was previously designed with the Adobe suite, there are more than likely characteristics of the illustrations that the OP will not be able to replicate in Word.

Answer (score 3):

1. When you paste from the Adobe programs, make sure you use **Paste Special** and select **Enhanced Metafile**
2. Then go into Word's **Picture Tools** ribbon and open up the
   **Layout** dialog box
3. You can lock the position in the Layout dialog box.

However, that may or may not work best for the final file, as the surrounding text may become irrelevant or break weirdly.

Also, it will be extremely difficult to duplicate layouts in Word that are created in these other products, as they are designed for different purposes and have different functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The below method only locks the image so it will not be moved when changing the text or margins. You will still be able to move the image.

In Microsoft Word paste your picture. Go to the `Page Layout` tab. Click on `Position` then `More Layout Options`. Under the `Text Wrapping tab`, make the picture either `Square` or `Tight`. Go to the `Position` tab and tick the box  `lock anchor` and untick the box `move with text`. Make sure `position` is `Absolute` relative to `Page`.

These directions are done in Microsoft Word 2010. Depending on your version the directions might vary slightly. You might also have a more difficult time re-creating the document in word but you will be able to lock images in place while others can edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue is to convert the vector image to a font (for example on fontastic.me), then install this created font en use it in word. It works perfect !

Comment: I wouldn't say it's the best, as the result is going to be monochromatic.

Comment: you have a point ;)